# Comparison Not Functioning Like It Should

Tags: verilog

I am trying to build a module that accepts two 16 bit inputs and depending a compare signal, evaluates a certain expression and sends a true (1) value to choice the output if the expression is evaluated as true.

This is my source code:

```
    module comparator(input [15:0] r15_register, sourceone_register , input [1:0] comp_signal, output reg choice);
    always @(*)begin
        if (comp_signal == 2'b00) begin
            //Check if soureceone is greater than r15.
            choice = (sourceone_register > r15_register)? 1:0;          
            end
        else if (comp_signal == 2'b01) begin
            //Check is sourceone is less than r15.
            choice = (sourceone_register <r15_register)? 1:0;
            end
        else if (comp_signal == 2'b10) begin
            //Check if sourceone is equal to r15.  
            choice = (sourceone_register == r15_register)? 1:0;
            end
        else
            choice <= 0;
    end 
endmodule
```

This is my testbench code:

```
module comparator_fixture();
reg [15:0] r15_register, sourceone_register;
reg [1:0] comp_signal;
wire choice;

comparator utt(.r15_register(r15_register), .sourceone_register(soureone_register), .comp_signal(comp_signal), .choice(choice));

initial begin
    #20;
    comp_signal = 2'b00;
    //Sourceone is greater than r15.
    r15_register = 4;
    sourceone_register = 6;
    //Sourceone is less than r15.
    #10;
    comp_signal = 2'b01;
    r15_register = 6;
    sourceone_register = 4;
    //Sourceone is equal to r15.
    #10;
    comp_signal = 2'b10;
    r15_register =7;
    sourceone_register =7;
    #30;
    $stop;
end
```

endmodule

When a `comp_signal` is given, it drives the output choice to X (an unknown state), and I haven't been able to figure out why. Can someone please offer some advice?

[image: Here is the waveform.]

Comment: It drives output to 'x' when? all the 60s which you simulated? what does it mean "*when a com_signal is given*"?

Comment: When I say "when a comp_signal is given" I mean that the signal can either be 2'b00, 2'b01, or 2'b10 and depending on what that input is, it is suppose to compare if the sourceone contents are greater than, less than or equal to r15's contents.

Comment: I uploaded a waveform to show when it goes to X. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I put your code into Vivado and get errors:

- undeclared symbol soureone_register, assumed default net type wire ...
- unexpected EOF

I found your waveform already 'weird' as `choice` was zero while nothing else had been given a value yet. So whatever you used to produce that waveform, it can't be the code you showed.

After I fixed the errors `choice` is no longer X.

Comment: Can you explain the errors to me? Because I didn't get those errors and I am using Vivado as well. That waveform is what pops up when I hit run simulation > behavorial simulation on Vivado, so I am not sure why it is 0ns to 20ns.

Comment: In regards to the simulation run, I removed the else statement that declared choice at 0 and when I ran the waveform then, choice was X for all 60ns of the simulation. Look to me that when the comp_signal was not given a value, choice went to 0 because of the last else statement, but when it was given a value it goes to X.

Answer (score 0):

Found my error, in my fixture there was an error in how I spelled "source" during the instantiation. I have included a waveform of the run after I fixed my spelling error.

[Here is the waveform with the correct output of "choice".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e31cV.png)

Comment: Good, next step is to improve the test-bench to also  test if `choice` goes low in each case :-)

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I added that to the testbench as well.